# Cannot process elements inside cdata

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to edit the link within the CDATA:

```
 <paragraph>
    <![CDATA[
        <strong><a href="http://example.com/2014/12/08/article-title">Article Title</a></strong>Article Excerpt.
    ]]>
 </paragraph>
```

The goal is to change paragraph to `<p>` and at the same time, add additional tags inside the link. For example, the desired output can be: (not all the `<paragraph>` have links in it, some contains only text)

```
<p>
    <strong><a href="http://example.com/2014/12/08/article-title?tacking_id=12345" style="font-size:1.1em; color:#067ab4; line-height:100%">Article Title</a></strong>Article Excerpt.
</p>
```

I have tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<p>]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</p>]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,'&lt;a href=&#34;') and contains(.,'&#34;>')]">

    <xsl:variable name="link" select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;a href=&#34;'), '&#34;>')"/>

    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<a href="]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$link"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&tracking_id=12345" ]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$link_style"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[>]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</a>]]></xsl:text>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There *are* no elements in CData - that's what it's for! Suppose you read a row from SQL into an xml file and one of those fields contained HTML with all its &wtf; entities, unterminated <br> tags and other invalid XML. You put it in a CData section to prevent XML from trying to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the XML processor is concerned, the CDATA in the `paragraph` node does not contain links, or tags, or anything other than a single text node. It is just a string of characters, so you have to resort to some tricksy string manipulation if you really wanted to change it.

The first problem you have is that in the template matching "paragraph", you don't do any `xsl:apply-templates`, so your second template that could match the text node under `paragraph` is never called.

You first template should therefore look like this

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, in the template matching the text node, this is where it gets nasty, but your main problem is that you do `<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>`. But it is a text node. A single text node. It has no child nodes on which you can match.

If you really, really wanted to get it to work this way, the template would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,'&lt;a href=&#34;') and contains(.,'&#34;>')]">
    <xsl:variable name="firstbit" select="substring-before(., '&lt;a href=&#34;')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="link" select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;a href=&#34;'), '&#34;>')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lastbit" select="substring-after(substring-after(., '&lt;a href=&#34;'), '&#34;>')"/>

    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$firstbit"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<a href="]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$link"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[?tracking_id=12345" ]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$link_style"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[>]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$lastbit"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This answer probably demonstrates why trying to manipulate CDATA is a bad idea.

Another less unpleasant way would be to do TWO XSLT transforms.

The first one would just look like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="paragraph">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="." />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would output the following:

```
<p>
    <strong><a href="http://example.com/2014/12/08/article-title">Article Title</a></strong>Article Excerpt.
</p>
```

It then becomes trivial to do the required transform the `a` tags in this then....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <a href="{@href}?tracking_id=12345" style="color:#067ab4;">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This then  outputs the following:

```
<p>
     <strong><a href="http://example.com/2014/12/08/article-title?tracking_id=12345" style="color:#067ab4;">Article Title</a></strong>Article Excerpt.
</p>
```

So, if you can change your input XML to eliminate the CDATA, then it becomes a whole lot easier.....

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you very much! I'll try your first solution. The problem is I don't control the feed - I cannot remove the CDATA, so had to find nasty ways to work with it :(

Comment: Just applied your solution to my script, works perfect, thank you so much Tim!